# Looking for a good mobile framework

Tags: mobile

I am looking for a good mobile framework. This is for a university library, providing access to some database resources, hours and the like.

I have heard good things about the MIT Mobile Web Project and I know that some schools like Bucknell have used it and been pretty happy. Does anyone have any experience with this framework or any others?

Thanks,

Comment: I received lots of useful suggestions. Is there a way to mark a question as answered by people providing a range of options, or do I still just need to pick one?

Answer (score 3):

I have heard lots of good things about the [jQuery Mobile Framework](http://jquerymobile.com/). It's still in alpha at the moment but it is usable.

Answer (score 2):

For a small (2k), cachable, compact and *jQuery-like* syntax for WebKit based mobile browsers try [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/)

- MIT license
- supports iOS, Android, Palm WebOS

Comment: Interesting, but seems pointless to use a library that is designed for a single rendering engine. One of the major benefits to using a framework like jQuery is the cross-browser compatibility. If you have to write the code multiple times for each mobile browser type, then it sorta defeats the purpose.

Comment: Agreed, but if you check out the current landscape of capable mobile devices, the vast majority use WebKit. iPad, iPhone, iPodTouch, Palm Pre & Pixi, Android, BlackBerry (new models), Playbook (I presume will be WebKit).  Building in hacks to handle IE6 bugs is pointless when every byte counts in mobile.

Comment: True. I guess it might be sufficient to provide a rich interface to 90% of users. I'm really not up to speed on mobile development.

Answer (score 0):

Add to that sencha touch, and http://jqtouch.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is one called [HawHaw](http://www.hawhaw.de), and there's something that facebook uses made up of the following items:

- [XHP](https://github.com/facebook/xhp) for PHP
- [Javelin JS](http://www.javelinjs.com/)

This probably the most modern approach.

[Facebook Engineering: one mobile site to serve thousands of phones](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/one-mobile-site-to-serve-thousands-of-phones/10150122073713920)